# Vim Substitute: How to replace multiple occurrences with additional parts in string

Tags: vim

I have a string like this:

```
"test", "test2", "test3"
```

I want to replace `test*` with some value. that means it would look like this after substitution:

```
"abc", "abc", "abc"
```

This what I tried so far:

```
:s/test\(\d\)/abc/g => didn't work as expected.
:s/test\p/abc/g => deletes quotes in first occurrence.
:s/test\d/abc/g => first occurrence remains unchanged.
```

Could you please me help with the right syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

substitute 'test' followed by zero or more digits:

```
:s/test\d*/abc/g
```